# The letter "y" won't print in macOS Terminal

Tags: bash, inputrc

I'm learning BASH scripting, and I upgraded my BASH to version 5.1 using Homebrew. When I try typing "y", I just get a sound. When I run a script with a letter "y" in it, I get the message “y: no key sequence terminator”. My research suggests that it has to do with the .inputrc file. That file contains only 4 lines:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
TAB: menu-complete
y
```

I've tried using nano to delete the "y" as the last line, but I can't write the file back to the directory.
Am I correct that the last "y" is the problem and should be deleted?
If so, how?
If not, what else could I try?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

PS: I don't have this problem when using the zsh shell.

I get the message " [ Cannot open file for writing: Permission denied ]" when I try to save the nano back to .inputrc.

I'm not sure what the second comment means - sed --in-place....?

SOLVED MY OWN PROBLEM! I used ‘sudo’ to get permission to write to .inputrc. I deleted the letter ‘y’ from the file, and then I could use the letter ‘y’ in the BASH command line.

Comment: try `sed --in-place '4d' .inputrc`?  Be sure you execute that as a user who is able to modify that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter `y` should not be on its own row in the `.inputrc` file, so you will have to remove it.

If that is not possible, it is probably due to the file having the wrong ownership.  The file might have the wrong ownership if you accidentally created it as the root (or some other) user.

The correct way to change the ownership back to the correct user, assuming you are currently logged in as that user and that you have access to the `sudo` tool for temporarily escalating your privileges, would be to use

```bash
sudo chown "$(id -u):$(id -g)" ~/.inputrc
```

The `id` command is here used to retrieve your user and group IDs, and `chown` is then used to set the user and group ownerships of the file.

You may then open the file in any editor and make the change.  You may also remove the 4th line of the file from the command line of your macOS system directly using

```bash
/usr/bin/sed -i '' 4d ~/.inputrc
```